Laravel Nova devtical/nova-qrcode-field package Not working on server
I am using devtical/nova-qrcode-field package to display a QRCode image field in laravel Nova, it works perfectly locally but when pushed to the server  (Amazon lightsail) for test it doesn't display.
This is the code for the QrCode Field
Qrcode::make('QR Code')
        ->resolveUsing(function ($value, $resource) {

            $dynamicLinks = app('firebase.dynamic_links');
            $url = env('LINK_DOMAIN') . '/restaurant?id=' . $resource->id;
            try {
                $link = $dynamicLinks->createDynamicLink($url);
                info("I got here o");
                info($link);
            } catch (FailedToCreateDynamicLink $e) {
                info('Error: ' . $e->getMessage());
                return 'Failed to create Link, Contact Administrator. ' . now();
            }
            return $link;
        }),

Here are images of the web page locally and on the server.
Local

Server

I Inspected browser elements and found a difference that could possibly be the problem, see images below
Local

<td class="px-2 py-2 whitespace-nowrap cursor-pointer dark:bg-gray-800 group-hover:bg-gray-50 dark:group-hover:bg-gray-900">
<span class="text-left" resource="[object Object]">
<img src="data:image/png;base64,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" class="qr-item" style="display: inline-block;">
</span>
</td>

Server

<td class="px-2 py-2 whitespace-nowrap cursor-pointer dark:bg-gray-800 group-hover:bg-gray-50 dark:group-hover:bg-gray-900">
<index-qrcode class="text-left" field="[object Object]" resource="[object Object]" resource-name="restaurants"></index-qrcode>
</td>

Please any Idea how i can go about fixing this or why the img tag changed to index-qrcode tag on the server.

Please share more details, like the different you've identified in text form

Hi Nico, Yea, i shared an image on the post of how it looked in HTML format for each case

Please share all details in text form, not hidden in screenshots

Understood Nico, I have added in the tags in text form
